# Pre-trained model in Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, torch, pre-trained-model

I just loaded the pre-trained model 3D resnet
https://github.com/kenshohara/3D-ResNets-PyTorch

I loaded this model in this way after i download from the link above the file 'resnext-101-kinetics.pth' :
[way i defined the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gi09.png)

this model work on a big dataset of videos (unfortunately i don't have enough space on my pc and i didn't find a link that i can download part of the data set). I just want to know if i load the model correctly and to know that this net is trained.
There is an option to be sure that the model loaded well?
I printed the state_dict and it prints the weights.

Answer (score 0):

It already includes the script to load the pretrained weights to the model. Please check the code from the line 168 - line 173:

https://github.com/kenshohara/3D-ResNets-PyTorch/blob/master/model.py#L168-L173

Change the value for `default` in the [opts.py](https://github.com/kenshohara/3D-ResNets-PyTorch/blob/d9847ea56b0d4bc7601a229099deb2b483539514/opts.py#L143) file, to the path of the file you downloaded `resnext-101-kinetics.pth`.

```
'--pretrain_path', default='path/to/resnext-101-kinetics.pth', type=str, help='Pretrained model (.pth)')
```

If there is no error appears when you run your code, then the pretrained file `resnext-101-kinetics.pth` is loaded properly.

Comment: Thanks! my code fail in the assert on line 171 (assert opt.arch == pretrain['arch']). i checked this problem and i saw this : https://github.com/kenshohara/3D-ResNets-PyTorch/issues/50 but they speak there on the resnet-34. so i have no idea how to fix this problem because the path that i gave is good ( resnext-101-kinetics.pth). thank you so much!